# freopen() equivalent for c++ streams

Tags: c++, c, io

When programming with c-style i/o I sometimes use freopen() to reopen stdin for testing purposes so that I don't have to retype the input over and over. I was wondering if there is an equivalent for c++ i/o streams. Also, I know that I can use pipes to redirect it on the command line/terminal/whateveritis but I was wondering if there was a way to do it inside my code (because as you can see, I'm not very knowledgeable about the cl/t/w).

Comment: Can you read the same data twice when you have two file descriptors of the same stream? If not, you can always use multiple instances of std::cin in C++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`freopen` also works with `cin` and `cout`. No need to search for something new.

```
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin); // redirects standard input
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout); // redirects standard output

int x;
cin >> x; // reads from input.txt
cout << x << endl; // writes to output.txt
```

**Edit:** From C++ standard 27.3.1:

> The object cin controls input from a stream buffer associated with the object stdin, declared in `<cstdio>`.

So according to the standard, if we redirect `stdin` it will also redirect `cin`. Vice versa for `cout`.

Comment: No it does not. This program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.. I have use it lot of times on visual studio and g++ and I haven't any problems. Could you please explain what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Just because something works on one implementation does not mean it's valid C++. Last I checked, it was *at best* implementation-defined whether changes to stdio were visible in the corresponding iostream or vice versa, and possibly worse.

Comment: @R.. from cplusplus.com `cin is an object of class istream that represents the standard input stream. It corresponds to the cstdio stream stdin.` So cin is connected with stdin and if we are redirecting `stdin` we are also redirecting `cin`. Same thing with `cout`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work but _is_ there a way to do it with just c++ style input features?

Comment: @quasiverse I don't think so. Even timus online judge is suggesting to use freopen for testing in C++. http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=cpp

Comment: @Ashot The cplusplus.com page was slightly ambiguous about it but timus seems pretty conclusive. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashot: In that case, does this preclude a C++ implementation from performing its own buffering, etc. on top of `stdio`? It seems like it does...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE You can disable this behavior with `std::sync_with_stdio(false);` so then C++ can do it's own buffering. See also [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151286/3809561) for how you can still redirect `std::cout` if you use `std::sync_with_stdio(false)`.

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

  // Read one line from stdin
  std::string line;
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  std::cout << line << "\n";

  // Read a line from /etc/issue
  std::ifstream issue("/etc/issue");
  std::streambuf* issue_buf = issue.rdbuf();
  std::streambuf* cin_buf = std::cin.rdbuf(issue_buf);
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  std::cout << line << "\n";

  // Restore sanity and read a line from stdin
  std::cin.rdbuf(cin_buf);
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/80ca417acb84858f) newsgroup posting explores your options.

> This is system dependent and the poster didn't indicate the
>   system, but cin.clear() should work.   I have tested the attached
>   program on a UNIX system with AT&T version's of iostreams.

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    for(;;) {
        if ( cin.eof() ) {
            cout << "EOF" << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
        char c ;
        if ( cin.get(c) ) cout.put(c) ;
    }
}
```

> Yes, that works okay in cfront and TC++.
>   In g++ where the problem first arose an additional action is required:

```
  cin.clear();
  rewind ( _iob ); // Seems quite out of place, doesn't it?
                   // cfront also accepts but doesn't
                   // require this rewind.
```

Though I note that this was in 1991, it should still work. Remember to use the now-standard `iostream` header, not `iostream.h`.

(BTW I found that post with the Google search terms "reopen cin c++", second result.)

Let us know how you get on. You could also just use `freopen`.

Comment: Mixing C stdio and C++ iostream usage like this is not valid and will result in implementation-defined or undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get how this relates to my question. Could you explain more?

Comment: @quasiverse: It's about re-opening STDIN through `cin`.

Comment: @R: I worried so. Then there is no way to do what the OP asks without UB.