# Redirecting std::cout when program is run as a service

Tags: c++, windows, cout

I have a c++ program that prints to the screen using std::cout.

Sometimes I need to run it as a service. Is there any way of seeing the cout outputs when it's running as a Windows service?

Redirecting the output to a file or some sort of debugging program would be ideal.

Obviously I could replace the cout with a function that writes to a file, and that's probably what I'll do, but I'm curious to know if there are other solutions.

Comment: On Unix systems, you can redirect the standard output, when you're starting the process, but I'm not familiar with something like this in Windows. Probably, it should exist.

Comment: Redirecting the standard output after I've started the process or piping is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try to do some research for such feature in Windows. There should be something like this. I'd google something like "redirect output of process in windows".

Comment: @KirilKirov: It does exist, `SetStdHandle`. It's not entirely _re_direction in this case since a service doesn't have standard I/O handles initially.

Answer (score 2):

There's basically infinite options.  The first few that come to mind:

**Pass around an ostream reference**

You could pass around an std::ostream reference:

```
void someFunc(std::ostream& out) {
    //someFunc doesn't need to know whether out is a file, cout, or whatever
    out << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

**Replace `cout` underlying buffer with a file**

Example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/):

```
streambuf *psbuf, *backup;
ofstream filestr;
filestr.open ("test.txt");

backup = cout.rdbuf();     // back up cout's streambuf

psbuf = filestr.rdbuf();   // get file's streambuf
cout.rdbuf(psbuf);         // assign streambuf to cout

cout << "This is written to the file";
```

There's a 1-liner with freopen, but I have a creeping feeling (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257664/567864) seems to reenforce it in the comments) that it's undefined behavior since stdin and cout can be un-synchronized.

```
freopen("/path/to/file", "r", stdout);
//cout is now writing to path/to/file
```

**A logging library**

Not sure of a good one of the top of my head, but you could go full out and use some type of logging library.  (There's also Windows events, though depending on what you're outputting, that might not make sense.)

**Piping**

I doubt this is possible with a Windows service, but if it is, there's always the classic redirection:

```
blah.exe > C:\path\file
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is `SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, your_new_handle)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class MyTerminal {
    std::stringstream terminalText;
}

class MyWindow {
public:
     void OnUpdate();
protected:
CTextbox m_textbox;
MyTerminal m_terminal;
}

void MyWindow::OnUpdate()
{
    m_textBox.setText(m_terminal.terminalText.str());
    m_terminal.terminalText.str(std::string());
}
```