# How redirect std::ostream to a file or /dev/null in c++ and linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a c++ application, which contains large amount of `std::cout`. It runs on linux 2.6.x. I need to test the performance of the application, so i am thinking of redirecting the `std::cout` to `/dev/null`. In C, i could simply use `dup2`. Is there an equivalent in c++ to redirect `std::ostream` to a file or `/dev/null`?

Comment: Note, I/O is usually one of the biggest bottlenecks.  If you start messing with that, can you really trust your numbers?

Comment: to effectively test the performance, you should really refactor the running code and separate it out of the i/o code. Probably make it a function..such that the function should not care where the data came from (either i/o or hard-coded)

Comment: possible duplicate of [freopen() equivalent for c++ streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams)

Comment: A note for Windows programmers: `dup2` method from _Potatoswatter_ works like a charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dup2` trick will still work in C++, since just like `<stdio.h>`, `<iostream>` is just a buffering layer atop the UNIX system calls.

You can also do this at the C++ level by disconnecting the buffer from `std::cout`:

```
std::cout.rdbuf( NULL );
```

Besides severing the relationship between `std::cout` and any actual output device, this will set the `std::ios::badbit` flag which will prevent any output conversions (e.g. numbers to text) from occuring. Performance should be much better than with the filesystem-level hack.

Comment: +1 for an informative post, but re "I need to test the performance of the application" / "Performance should be much better than with the filesystem-level hack." - it could be argued that avoiding conversions is no longer testing the application performance.

Comment: @TonyD Asking how to test performance is a loaded question. Performance is tested by carefully replicating real-world conditions, and nobody here can answer that. I'm assuming he wants to test how it would perform if it weren't for all the output. If that's not a practical use, then the question is pointless.

Comment: This is really good answer. A quick Question, can you suggest some resource to learn more about iostreams?

Comment: @Jimm I don't personally use any resources besides the ISO standard document. But there's always http://cppreference.com and I have this in my bookmarks: http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/streams.txt

Comment: @Potatoswatter: in my experience, it's common to want to know the performance including the generation of output, but without the time taken by the I/O device to write.  For example, to be able to say things like "on that spec CPU/ram etc. it'll take 10 second + however long your disk needs to write the output", or "generation of output took 12 seconds, but when writing that to disk it took 40 seconds overall - how about we get a SSD?".

Comment: @TonyD That can be determined without code modification or redirection tricks by a utility such as UNIX `time` or most any process monitor. I/O contributes to "system" time not "user process" time.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: no it can't - there may be a lot of other things contributing to "system time" other than the output to `std::cout`, so you'd want to include the unavoidable aspects of system time in your total.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the exact same thing in C++.  Both C and C++ both rely on the underlying operating system for IO, and redirecting fd 1 will affect `std::cout` just like it affects `stdout`.

(of course for testing you can just run the command with `> /dev/null` on the command line...)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to [symlink your file to /dev/null](http://linuxzoo.net/page/wildcards_links_soft.html).

```
% ln -s /dev/null core
% ls -l core
lrwx-xr-x  1 john users 9 Nov 18 12:26 core -> /dev/null
```

To truly test your program speed however I would suggest to comment out the writes to your file and calculate the execution time difference, because writing to /dev/null might have different overhead than writing to a normal file.