# Collect stdout output from a console app with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, stdout

I have a console application written with C++. Is there any way to collect all `stdout` output from it to string/pipe/memory array?

PS. I need to do this from within the console app that I'm needing to collect `stdout` from. Or, in other words, it is collecting from itself.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it's from within the app itself you already have the output, send it elsewhere. To answer the actual question, yes it's possible. Having an app that just logs stdout makes sense but I don't get where you're going with this.

Comment: If file output is okay, you can use `freopen()` to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To redirect it to a `string`, you can use a `std::stringstream`

```
std::stringstream buffer;
std::streambuf * old = std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());
```

Then, if you do:

```
std::cout << "Example output" << std::endl;
std::string text = buffer.str();
```

You will see that `text` now contains `"Example output\n"`.

Comment: My output mostly comes from C-like calls to `_tprintf(_T("Some line1\n"));` that doesn't seem to be caught by your approach. Any idea why?