# C++ - Why fflush(stdout) does not work with iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio, fflush

I was reading about `freopen()` and realized that if we specify stdin/stdout to it, the function will work even if we code using cin/cout.

Researching a little bit, I had found this link  [freopen() equivalent for c++ streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams), where one of the users answered:

> From C++ standard 27.3.1:
>   "The object `cin` controls input from a stream buffer associated with the object `stdin`, declared in `<cstdio>`."
>   
>   So according to the standard, if we redirect `stdin` it will also redirect `cin`. Vice versa for `cout`.

Also saw something similar on CPPReference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf), associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

That's where it got a little confusing, as I was also reading about flushes and noticed that fflush(stdout) simply won't work with cin/cout.

For example, this sample code won't print anything:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n;
    cout << "Please, enter a number: \n";
    fflush(stdout);
    cin >> n;
}
```

While this code below will print to output.txt:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    cout << "Some string";
    while (true);
}
```

Removing `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` from the first sample code, it behaves as expected. And `freopen()` works anyway (with or without it).

So the question is: why fflush(stdout) does not work with iostream, while freopen(..., stdout) works? Maybe, this question can get even deeper: to what extension is cin/cout associated with stdin/stdout?

Sorry for the long post. I tried to be as detailed and concise as possible.

I hope it is understandable.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I put `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` and `cin.tie(0);` on purpose.

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer as to freopen works and fflush doesn't except that it's implementation-dependent and there's no standard guaranteeing cstdio working together with iostream, so it seems like a waste of time to even try. If you want redirection, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Comment: What compiler/library specifically "will print to output.txt"? I am not observing that with gcc/libstdc++ nor with clang/libc++ on my linux: the file remains empty while the loop spins.

Answer (score 5):

My first question is "why would you want to"? There is a [`std::ostream::flush()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) function for this purpose, so use that e.g. `cout.flush();`.

The reason that it "doesn't work" is that the buffer which is flushed with `fflush(FILE* f)` is not the same buffer that is used for `std::ostream` (or at least it's not guaranteed that it will be). It's quite likely that `std::ostream::flush()` does call `fflush(FILE*)` on the underlying file object that is part of the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the calls `ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` and `cin.tie(0)` that you have put in "on purpose" is to ensure (1)  that C I/O streams (`stdout`, etc) are not synchronised with their C++ counterparts (`std::cout`, etc) and (2) to ensure that `stdout` and `stdin` are not tied (i.e. reading from `stdin` does not necessarily cause `stdout` to be flushed).

That is why `fflush(stdout)` does not affect `std::cout` in your example.   You have specifically disabled such an effect, and the two may be buffered separately.

The effect of `freopen()` on any C++ stream that may be synchronised with the supplied file handle is undefined.    In practice, there may be some buffers used in common, which explains what you are seeing - at least, with your compiler/library.   But that behaviour is not guaranteed with other implementations.