# How to output to stdin from a Windows application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is a snippet of my code:

```
AttachConsole(-1);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin); //this doesn't seem to do anything
int n = 0;
cin >> n;
cout << n + 1;
FreeConsole();
WNDCLASSA MainWindow = { 0 };
MainWindow.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW;
MainWindow.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
MainWindow.hInstance = hInst;
//here the window gets created etc.
```

Obviously the usage of the console here is basic, but that should do for this question. The problem is that functions like `cin` or `scanf` are not working. `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `printf` work fine, but the input functions don't do anything. How can I make `stdin` work (preferrably with `cin`)?

Comment: have you tried `std::cin.clear()` after `freopen()`ing the streams?

Comment: Why aren't you using Unicode

Comment: @J. Doe adding `cin.clear()` after `freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin)` doesn't work.

Comment: @stackptr I don't need Unicode and I don't see why that is relevant for this question

Comment: You could try a different method than `freopen()` described in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15836/Writing-to-and-read-from-the-console-From-a-GUI-ap) article.

Comment: Interesting idea, but visual studio doesn't allow me to change the value of `stdin` (actually, it is `#define`d)

Comment: You don't check the return values (**big** NO-NO). Check https://gist.github.com/Xsoda/3120099.

Comment: The article isn't suggesting to change `stdin` but its pointee.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get console output in C++ with a Windows program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program)

Comment: Are you including `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`? According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams what you're doing _should_ work. As CristiFati suggested, check the returns on `freopen`. I'd suggest that after redirecting `stdin`, test it with (e.g.) `fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)` first to verify that `stdin` was redirected properly. Then, you can move on to testing it with `cin` This two step approach will help isolate if `freopen` is failing or if something extra is needed to get `cin` to work (e.g. `cin.clear()`) as others have suggested

Comment: @CristiFati in the article the pointer to the new FILE wasn't dereferenced, that's why I got confused. It kept telling me that I was trying to assign FILE* to FILE. I am still trying to implement that

Comment: @Craig Estey here is what I included: `windows.h`, `io.h`, `conio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`, `iostream`

Comment: @DarkAtom "I am still trying to implement that" the function in my answer uses the method described in the article.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it makes a difference, but I'd use `cstdio` as that is the _idiomatic_ way to do it. `cstdio` will [probably] include `stdio.h` but do it in a way that allows `cin` to work. If you were _only_ using `stdin` and _not_ `cin`, including `stdio.h` would/should be fine. Intermixing them takes some special care (e.g. you need to "tell" `cin` that you're doing this so that it will use `FILE` buffering instead of doing its own--implementation dependent). So, what are the results of the `fgets` test?

Comment: @CraigEstey `<cstdio>` doesn't do any funny things before including `<stdio.h>` (Visual Studio).

Comment: @J. Doe replaced `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` with `cstdio` and `cstdlib`, respectively. No changes in behaviour. I believe cin has nothing to do with `cstdio`, but with `iostream`, the only difference being that one is in namespace `std`, while the other one isn't.

Comment: @DarkAtom You should take better care of who you refer to in your comments. (2nd time wrong person)

Comment: I was actually refering to CristiFati and you

Comment: Use `AllocConsole` if the there is no parent process with console window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` program will be detached from the console right at its launch and the command processor `cmd.exe` waits for user input again. So `stdin` is already in use before your programm can attempt any input operation.

Actually,

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    AttachConsole(-1);

    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);

    std::cout.clear();
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

works as expected when run from the command prompt using `start /wait foobar.exe`. (`foobar.exe` must be built as x64 to work that way on x64 Windows. Trying with an x86 executable gives funny error messages.)

See [How do I write a program that can be run either as a console or a GUI application?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/) for a discussion about the topic.

Comment: it says `_O_TEXT` is undefined

Comment: `_O_TEXT` is defined in `<fcntl.h>`

Comment: I called this from WinMain and checked if the return value is false. If it is, display a Windows message box, otherwise not. When launched without a console it displays that (obviously), but when launched with a console, it doesn't display that but neither stdin nor stdout are working.

Comment: Do you check the return value of your `AttachConsole(-1);`? Whats the parent process anyway?

Comment: yes, I checked it, it only returns `TRUE` when there actually is a calling console

Comment: Do you want to say your parent is `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Yes, I am on windows so I use `cmd.exe` because there are no other options (I don't think using powershell would change anything)

Comment: Once a program with `SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is started from a console, it gets detached from it. The command processor won't wait for the program to end but display a new prompt immediatly and wait for user input. How could that work if your program were able to steal the consoles stdin??

Comment: The `freopen()` method actually works if you run the executable from a `cmd.exe` using `start /wait foobar.exe`. But on W10 x64 only with x64 executables. You get funny error messages if you try with x86 exes.

Comment: well that is good to know, but what is the purpose of `AttachConsole` then? Shouldn't it reattach the program to cmd?

Comment: `AttachConsole()`s purpose is to attach to the console of a parent process that either has a console because it is a `SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` exe or one that used `AllocConsole()`.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/ for a discussion of the topic.

Comment: Ok, using `AllocConsole` and the `freopen` method works fine. For some reason attaching to existing consoles is a problem, but creating one is not

Comment: Ok, I found a long shot, but it is pretty dumb in my opinion. Attaching to the console and then killing the `cmd.exe` associated with that console using `system("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe");` will leave the console window open and freely available to the application. After the application is done with the console, it can start cmd.exe using `system("start cmd.exe");`. The only downsides to this is that it changes the PID of `cmd.exe` and it kills all cmd windows (although I believe that this can be worked around by killing only the process with the parent's pid)

Comment: I'd just use a console application and use the console "legally" or `FreeConsole()` it otherwise.