# After freopen(..,"r",stdin) + fclose(stdin), further std::cin doesn't work

Tags: c++, file, cin, fclose, freopen

```
int main(){

    int a,b;

    std::cin >> a >> b;           // first

    freopen("test.txt","r",stdin);
    std::cin >> a >> b;           // second
    fclose(stdin);
    cout << a << ", " << b << endl;

    freopen("test2.txt","r",stdin);
    std::cin >> a >> b;          // third
    fclose(stdin);
    cout << a << ", " << b << endl;

    std::cin >> a >> b;          // fourth

    return 0;
}
```

This block of code is to have a mixture of input from terminal and files.
The first, second and third cin works fine, but the fourth failed. It seems that fclose(stdin) has no function here.

Comment: `stdin` and `cin` are typically going to be the same file.  How did you expect to be able to read from a file after you closed it?

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257509/freopen-equivalent-for-c-streams).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [c++ draft 27.4.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf):

> The object cin controls input from a stream buffer associated with the object stdin, declared in <cstdio>.

Reading from `std::cin` is the same as reading from `stdin`. This means that after `fclose(stdin)` using `std::cin` is like calling `scanf("%d", &a)`.

This is exactly what happens in the third case, where `fclose(stdin)` is called before reading `std::cin`. In contrast, cases 1-3 the code reads `std::cin` before `fclose(stdin)`.

Reading from a closed `stdin` is possibly undefined. Here is what the [c11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) has to say about it:

> 7.21.7.1 The fgetc function
>
> ...
>
> ```
> int fgetc(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:**
>   If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-
>   of-file indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF. Otherwise, the
>   fgetc function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream.
>   If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function
>   returns EOF.

This text covers all cases of reading from an open stdin (successful, end-of-file, and a read error), but they don't refer to the case when the stream is closed due to `fclose`. I could not find anything in the standard that covers this case, which means that the case is undefined.

**Conclusion**: reading from `std::cin` after `fclose(stdin)`, without any further `freopen` is undefined behavior. Trying to read a closed C stream might refer to freed resources.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I can also reach this conclusion after my tiny test. So what confused me now is how to make my std::cin return to receiving words from terminal. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: @ysgc  you can save the original stdin descriptor before you start `saved_fd = strdup(0)`, and when you finally need to restore stdin, you `close(0)` and then `strdup(saved_fd)`. But don't forget to clear any eof and error flags and the buffered data.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried :

saved_fd = strdup(0);
close(0);

But the close function is not defined, do I need to include some head file?